# How can i apply less than ,greater than operators for a column in a DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, pan

These are the conditions to apply on column K

```
enter code here
    k<-0.023
   -0.023<=k<-0.011
   -0.011<=k<-0.036
   -0.036<=k<0.0072
    0.0072<=k<0.042
     0.042<k<0.084`enter code here`
     k>=0.84
```

if the First  condition satisfy then return "A"
if the second  condition satisfy then return "B"
if the third  condition satisfy then return "C"
if the fourth  condition satisfy then return "D"
if the Fifth  condition satisfy then return "E"    so on
i have column K how can i apply the above conditions

Comment: [`np.digitize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a couple lines for example. You can extrapolate from here.

```
if k<-0.023:
   return A
elif -0.023<=k and k<-0.011:
   return B
elif -0.011<=k and k<-0.036:
   return C
```